# Did Guinness Book of Records screw this up?

Tags: math-history

**Crossposted on [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2435/did-guinness-book-of-records-screw-this-up)**

See [Guinness Book of Records](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/longest-standing-maths-problem-(ever)). Did they screw this up? It says that Fermat's Last Theorem was the longest open problem - with only 365 years. However, there are Greek problems that were longer open:

1. Squaring the circle, proposed before 428 BCE (Anaxagoras worked on it, who died in 428 BCE), solved 1882, open for
   at least 2.310 years.
2. Doubling the cube, proposed before 430 BCE, solved 1837, open for at least 2.267 years.
3. Archimedes Cattle Problem, proposed before 212 BCE, solved 1880, open for at least 2.092 years.
4. Angle trisection, solved 1837.

Questions:

1. Is there a reason why Guinness Book of Records listed Fermat's Last Theorem?
2. Are there problems that were even longer open than the above (Egyptian, Chinese, Indian, Babylonian?), or can you find a reference that the problems above were proposed earlier?

---

**Edit:** Gregory Grant e-mailed Guinness Book of Records.

Comment: Well this question would be better at HSM

Comment: @Rememberme I will migrate it to there if no answer is given tomorrow.

Comment: I feel the answer lies in what they define as an open maths problem.

Comment: Someone should tell them that Fermat's Last Theorem isn't $xn+yn=zn$.

Comment: @wythagoras There's not much to answer except yes, they got it wrong.  Very wrong.   Why don't you try to write them a letter to let them know.  And maybe also ask what process could have led them to get it that wrong.

Comment: Well @wythagoras I can bet you this wont be answered on MSE until and unless there is a guinness book of world records official  in MSE who is a mathematician

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt They also said "no solution in integers" which is incorrect, should specify non-trivial solutions

Comment: @wythagoras Maybe they don't consider the cattle problem open for 2,000 years because it was lost for most of that time and only rediscovered in 1773.  So there weren't people working on it for 2,000 years, in fact people worked on it for less than FLT, so by that criteria it is ok.  Could it be that the other problems took similar hiatuses and that was the logic used by Guiness?

Comment: Yes that might be an aswer

Comment: I would count the Odd Perfect Number conjecture to be the longest unsolved problem of mathematics.  See this [Harvard presentation](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/seminars/perfect/handout.pdf) for more information.

Comment: @ArnieDris Interesting presentation, but someone should tell them that $2^{242643801}-1$ is not know to be prime or composite.  (I think) I believe the first 2 in the exponent should be removed.

Comment: @wythagoras, for an updated list of Mersenne primes, it is best to refer to the [GIMPS](http://www.mersenne.org/primes/) page, of course.  =)

Comment: I believe that Oliver made a typo with that one.

Comment: They also spelled it "theorum" in one place, which makes it hard to take them too seriously...

Comment: @wythagoras I see that people can leave comments on their page - though nobody has yet.  Why don't you leave a comment straightening the record out and maybe some official will see it?  I would leave a comment myself, but they've done that idiotic thing where you have to have a facebook account to post comments on their site.  And I have no facebook account, so I can't do it.

Comment: @wythagoras Well I see nobody left any comment on their page.  So I went ahead and emailed them a detailed explanation of their mistake.  Let's see if they act on it.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Thank you! I was actually planning on doing that, but I hadn't done it yet.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt I would give them the benefit of the doubt and say that it is due to a type formatting error (hence the randomly bolded and underlined $n$'s)

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt I didn't mention the typos just the fact that FLT is not the longest unsolved problem "ever"

Comment: @GregoryGrant Isn't FLT usually Fermat's Little theorem, not Fermat's Last Theorem?

Comment: @wythagoras I've seen it used extensively for both.  Plus, I doubt anybody would have trouble understanding me from the context of this thread.

Comment: I'm closing this question because it was cross-posted to and answered on [hsm](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2435/did-guinness-book-of-records-screw-this-up).